# How to display specific classes on an element with an intersectionObserver/Scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

Here are three section in my page in vue.

```
<section id="home">Home</section>
<section id="about">About</section>
<section id="contact">Contact</section>
```

When I click on Navbar Link it scrolls me to the appropriate section.
Here is my router-link.

```
<router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
<router-link to="/#about">About</router-link>
<router-link to="/#contact">Contact</router-link>
```

By default these classes are added to link of active page.

```
router-link-active router-link-exact-active

<a href="/" class="router-link-active router-link-exact-active" data-v-41458b80="" aria-current="page">Home</a>
<a href="/#about" class="router-link-active router-link-exact-active" data-v-41458b80="" aria-current="page">About</a>
<a href="/#contact" class="router-link-active router-link-exact-active" data-v-41458b80="" aria-current="page">Contact</a>
```

But as all the sections are on same index page these classes are added to all the navbar links.
Is there a way to add a custom class when a page is at particular section?

Comment: I have tried your method many times with some modifications. But the thing is it works well when the path is completely different after the "/". Like "/test" and '/blog'. I want it to work for paths that include hash like '/test/#contact'. My content is on the same page.  I guess I need to add classes with javascript when the page is scrolled.

Comment: Something like this so? https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#markdown-plugins

Comment: Like this https://demo.themesuccess.com/templates/angus/dark_solid_grid_portfolio.html   see how the Navbar links are highlighted when page is scrolled.

Comment: I've edited my example with a scroll-spy link and a whole homemade intersection observer to change the path with a hash once reached a specific threshold of a block.

Comment: I will try that out.

Comment: I tried using your code but it's difficult for me to understand how it will work. And also I dropped the idea of doing this task.

Comment: The intersection observer is some manual thing that will allow you to have more flexibility and do exactly what you tell it to do. Otherwise, if it's too complex, you can still follow the usage of the `vue2-scrollspy` package and get an idea on how to write the whole thing thatnks to this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ibufu/nw0zczLx/ It is pretty self-explanatory. Maybe try this one into your project and come back here (with your code) to see if you still have some issues.

Comment: Yes, I will try that out and let you know.

Comment: Hi, any news about this one? Does my solution work?

Comment: No update on it till now. I will work on it later. I do have a question. Just like we have vue2-scrollspy for Vue, so do we have anything for Gatsby (React Js), I am currently working on Gatsby projects.

Comment: Scrollspy is a generic Browser API thing, so it's available in any framework yeah.

Comment: Thank You. Found it on Bootstrap 5. Will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an intersection observer like [in this example](https://i.imgur.com/dIxMzUB.mp4), you can use the following code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API">
      Intersection observer example
    </a>

    <p
      v-observe-visibility="{
        callback: resetHashUrl,
        intersection: {
          threshold: 0.5,
        },
      }"
      style="background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%); height: 100vh"
    >
      top block (triggered at 50% of the block)
    </p>

    <p
      v-observe-visibility="{
        callback: (isVisible, entry) => pushNewHash(isVisible, entry, 'center'),
        intersection: {
          threshold: 0.7,
        },
      }"
      style="background-color: hsl(210, 17%, 40%); color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); height: 100vh"
    >
      center block (triggered if at least 70% of the block visible aka threshold value)
    </p>

    <p
      v-observe-visibility="{
        callback: (isVisible, entry) => pushNewHash(isVisible, entry, 'end'),
        intersection: {
          threshold: 0.3,
        },
      }"
      style="background-color: hsl(210, 50%, 13%); color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); height: 100vh"
    >
      end block (triggered if at least 30% of the block visible aka threshold value)
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ObserveVisibility } from 'vue-observe-visibility'

Vue.directive('observe-visibility', ObserveVisibility)

export default {
  methods: {
    resetHashUrl(isVisible, _entry) {
      if (isVisible) history?.replaceState(null, null, ' ')
    },
    pushNewHash(isVisible, _entry, newHash) {
      if (isVisible) location.hash = newHash
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

It's relying on [vue-observe-visibility](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility) and working pretty great, not a lot of configuration needed!

---

If you're looking for a simpler scroll-spy like [this one](https://ibufu.github.io/vue2-scrollspy/), you can use this package: https://github.com/ibufu/vue2-scrollspy

---

EDIT with a maybe more adapted example.
This snippet of code if you want to have some classes applied depending of the route you are on, or for which you want to pass a parameter.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button :class="{ 'custom-class': isOnSpecificPath('/test') }">Click me</button>
    <button :class="{ 'custom-class': isOnSpecificPath('/index') }">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    isOnSpecificPath(pathToTest) {
      return this.$route.path === pathToTest
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.custom-class {
  color: hsl(39, 100%, 46%);
  font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
```

[image]