# trigger vue-typed-js animation when element is in view

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using vue-typed-js library to trigger typing animation with  nuxt.js.It works perfectly on load, but I want to trigger this animation when user scrolls to that particular section. Basically controlling typing animation so they work only when element is in view. See this example in wordpress https://www.ennostudio.com,

here is my code for second section of the website.
added v-observe-visibility which works as well for adding classes for elements in view. am also using i18n for string translations.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <b-container class="enno_clients section">
            <b-row>
                <b-col cols="6">
                    <h6>02 / {{ $t('home.clients.subheading') }}</h6>
                    <vue-typed-js 
                    v-observe-visibility="{ callback: isViewableNow, once: true }"
                    :class="{ 'visible': showAnimation, 'invisible': !showAnimation }"
                    :typeSpeed="30" :showCursor="false" :strings="[ $t('home.clients.heading') ]" >
                        <h2 class="main_hero_heading typing"></h2>
                    </vue-typed-js>

                </b-col>
                <b-col cols="6" >
                    asd

                </b-col>
            </b-row>
         </b-container>
    </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .visible { visibility: visible; opacity:1; }
    .invisible { visibility: hidden; opacity:0; }
</style>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Clients',
    data() {
      return {
        show_hero_content: true,
        showAnimation: false,
        VueTypedJs: ''
      }
    },
    methods:{
        isViewableNow(isVisible, entry) {
            this.showAnimation = isVisible;
            console.log('isViewableNow');
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.show_hero_content = false;  


    },


}

</script>
```

Comment: So, what is not working here?

Comment: i want to trigger vue-typed-js animation on scroll to that section. right now it starts the animation on load. and when you scroll to second section its already half way animated. check this wordpress example https://www.ennostudio.com, see how heading typing animations are triggering when in view. –

Comment: Can you please give a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265585/8816585