# How to make lazy-load html tags in NuxtJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxtjs. I am making page called photos which shows a lot of DOM because the api I fetch photos doesn't provide pagination queries (page, limit). Currently it returns data containing 5000 photos.

For performance, I want to find a away to render only html tags that is visible in viewport. Other html tags should be lazy render until user scroll down. I have tried nuxt-lazy-load but this package only lazy load the image, it still render all html tags.

I would highly appreciate all advices. Thank you.

I use Nuxt 2.15.8, Vue 2.7.10.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Page Photos</h1>
    <div v-if="photos.length > 0">
      <div v-for="(photo, index) in photos" :key="photo.id"> **(I want to lazy render this element until user scroll down to here)**
        <h5>{{ `${index + 1}. ${photo.title}` }}</h5> 
        <img
          :alt="photo.title"
          :src="photo.url"
          width="600"
          height="600"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(context.$constants.photosApi).then((r) =>
        r.json()
      );
      return {
        photos: response || [],
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      return {
        photos: [],
      };
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller) is what you're looking for.
It will render in the DOM, only the elements visible in your current viewport (you can double check by inspecting the DOM and seeing that there is no more elements than the ones you see).

As for the lazy-load of images, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72232543/8816585
You can of course totally mix both techniques.

Comment: @vanminhquangtri did it helped you anywhow? Do you still have an issue or is it solved?